# problem withscrapy.response.follow () in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, callback, scrapy, yield

I´m new in scrapy and I have a little problem. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy


class SubcategoriasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subCategorias'
    start_urls = ['https://donvino.com.ar/categoria-producto/bodegas']

    def parse(self, response):
        bodegas = response.css('ul.menu#menu-bodegas li')
        for bodega in bodegas:
            url = bodega.css("a::attr(href)").get()
            #name_bodega = bodega.css('a::text').get() 
            yield response.follow(url,callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self,response):
        vinos = response.css('a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link')#no se puede dejar espacio vacío entre palabras, hay que poner un punto
        
        for vino in vinos:      

            yield {
              
                'nombre' : vino.css('h2::text').get(),
                'precio' : str(vino.css('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount::text').get()).replace(",", "")

            }
```

I need to add name_bodega = bodega.css('a::text').get() in def parse_items()...something like this:

```
yield {
                'name_bodega' :  ............
                'nombre' : vino.css('h2::text').get(),
                'precio' : str(vino.css('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount::text').get()).replace(",", "")

            }
```

the problem is that name_bodega is not in vino...so...I don´t know how to solve it...is there any way to add the name bodega ??.
Thanks in advance!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use meta to pass item between callback function

```
class SubcategoriasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subCategorias'
    start_urls = ['https://donvino.com.ar/categoria-producto/bodegas']

    def parse(self, response):
        bodegas = response.css('ul.menu#menu-bodegas li')
        for bodega in bodegas:
            url = bodega.css("a::attr(href)").get()
            name_bodega = bodega.css('a::text').get() 
            yield response.follow(url,callback=self.parse_items,meta={'item':{"name_bodegae": name_bodega}})

    def parse_items(self,response):
        vinos = response.css('a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link')#no se puede dejar espacio vacío entre palabras, hay que poner un punto
        
        for vino in vinos:      

            yield {
                'name_bodega':response.meta.get("item")['name_bodegae'], # or -> response.meta.get("item")["name_bodegae"]
                'nombre' : vino.css('h2::text').get(),
                'precio' : str(vino.css('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount::text').get()).replace(",", "")

            }
```

see detaisls here [scrapy: understanding how do items and requests work between callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589136/scrapy-understanding-how-do-items-and-requests-work-between-callbacks)

Comment: Thank u very much Samsul! You've been very helpful. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: if you found  it helpful please up vote and accept it, so that in future any one can get help from it

Comment: Yes!, I tried but I got this message: " Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.". I don´t know waht to do!.

Comment: please accept the anser. There is a tick mark.  see the link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I think it´s done!. Thank You Very Much For Your Patience !!!